# Add static route to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, static-routes

My IP from my router is: `192.168.15.26`

I connect to a VPN using Cisco VPN which assigns a new interface with the IP: `192.168.10.231`

Now, through the VPN, I need to access an MSSQL database to 192.168.15.36 but it doesn't allow me and it was suggested that I added a static route but it doesn't seem to be helping. These are the current routes that I have:
[image]

When using `psping` I can ping the destination from the `VPN Interface`:
[image]

How can I setup the routes so that I can access `192.168.15.36` from the `VPN` interface?

Comment: The network 192.168.15.0 needs to be advertised as a protected network on the VPN server which I assume is probably a Cisco ASA. Do you have access to the head end to reconfigure it? If not, contact who does. You do not need a route on your computer, nor can you force it. The configuration is done on the head end and the configuration is sent down to the VPN client.

Comment: @Appleoddity Thanks for your assistance, I really appreciate it! I just updated the post with a picture showing that I can ping the destination from the VPN using psping. I'm not sure how to interpret this. I do not have access to configure the end unfortunately.